How to set the grammer file to parse in any order?
I'm creating a jj tree file and how to make it parse in any order ?
query1 = CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Users DEFAULT  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci ;

query2 = CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Users DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 

I can parse only in single order .
I want both the orders to be parsed
